# KeyCloak H2 DB load issue while updating from 13.0 to 22.0.4

Tags: keycloak, version, upgrade

I have a KeyCloak 13.0 setup on linux env, with H2 DB.
Now, I am planning to update it to latest version (22.0.4).

My older steup is at `/root/keycloak/keycloak-13.0`
Latest setup at `/root/keycloak/keycloak-22.0.4/`

As h2 - 1.4.197 is being used by old KeyCloak, I generated the SQL file for DB migration using below command:
`java -cp h2-1.4.197.jar org.h2.tools.Script -url jdbc:h2:./standalone/data/keycloak -user sa -password sa`

This generated the backup.sql file.

Now using this sql file, I have generated latest DB file with H2-2.2.220 jar using below command :

`java -cp com.h2database.h2-2.2.220.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:./keycloak -script backup.sql -user sa -password sa -options FROM_1X`

With the generated DB file, I have updated the `conf/keycloak.conf` file as below:

```
# The username of the database user.
db-username=sa

# The password of the database user.
db-password=sa

# The full database JDBC URL. If not provided, a default URL is set based on the selected database vendor.
db-url=jdbc:h2:/root/keycloak/keycloak-22.0.4/data/keycloak
```

Now, when I am starting the serer, getting `Could not obtain connection to query metadata: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-220]` error.

```
2023-10-16 17:12:47,750 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': Wrong user name or password [28000-220]

2023-10-16 17:12:47,753 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-220]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:522)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:188)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:393)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:206)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:338)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:122)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:322)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:232)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:536)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:517)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried opening the generated db file (/root/keycloak/keycloak-22.0.4/data/keycloak.mv.db) with latest h2 jar and able to open with the sa as username and password. When it comes to keycloak its throwing error as invalid credentials.

What I am missing here ?

Earlier, all the details are mentioned in  standalone.xml file, now I moved required details to keycloak.conf file. Kc.sh is able to pick the other details like https port, hostname properly, but failing to load the DB creds. Is there any other config file needs to be updated for setting the DB user name and password ?

Comment: did you solve the issue i am also trying migrate h2 database to cloud?